# Using CVXPY with IBM's CLEX Cloud

Tags: cplex, cvxpy, docplex

How can one use IBM's CPLEX Decision Optimization Cloud[1] with CVXPY? If I have CPLEX installed locally, I can have cvxpy output an LP, SAV, or MPS file which I can then send to IBM's cloud service. However, this requires a local cplex install plus a run of the solver locally.  Is it possible to have CVPXY output an LP file without running the solver? And is it possible without a CPLEX install or license? Thanks,

[1] https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/marketplace/decision-optimization-cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a bit of a hack, but you can set the  CPLEX [deterministic time limit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/DetTiLim.html) parameter to 0. This should result in a very short “solve”, but still write out the model in the format you specified. The local CPLEX installation is required.

**EDIT**: In case you aren't already aware of this, you could use [docplex](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/optimization-modeling/modeling-for-python/) (can be pip installed from [here](https://pypi.org/project/docplex/)) instead of CVXPY. This would allow you to create the model and send it to the cloud *without* needing a local CPLEX installation and without even having to write anything to disk.